# How to CopyFilesOverSSH without parent source path in Azure?

Tags: azure, ssh

I am copying with

```
source_path: 'SparkJobs/pyspark'
target_path: '/home/myhome/sparkWithMonitoring'
python_subdir: 'v01/mydir/SPARK/pyspark'

...

- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
        displayName: Copying files
        inputs:
          sshEndpoint: 'myserver'
          contents: '$(source_path)/*'
          targetFolder: '$(target_path)/$(python_subdir)'
          readyTimeout: '20000'
```

and it copies to `$(target_path)/$(python_subdir)/$(source_path)/*`.

How to drop parent part and copy directly to destination?

I was also trying `contents: '$(source_path)/**'` with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked:

```
 - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
        displayName: Copying files
        inputs:
          sshEndpoint: 'myserver'
          sourceFolder: '$(source_path)'
          contents: '**'
          targetFolder: '$(target_path)/$(python_subdir)'
          readyTimeout: '20000'
```

I deduced it from Azure Web UI pipeline editor

[image]